# How can the shadows around windows be removed from Mate with Lightdm?

Tags: display-manager, shadow

There is a shadow around each window in Mate. If it matters I run Lightdm. How can the shadows be completely disabled for all windows regardless of the application?

Answer (score 6):

Go to Control Center -> Look and Feel -> Windows -> General

Remove the check box from "Enable software compositing window manager"

Answer (score 0):

It is now 2024.  The old ways to disable shadows don't seem to work, but I found that if I change the compositor to anything other than the builtin compositor the shadows go away.

Preferences -> Mate Tweak -> Windows -> Window Manager -> Marco (No Compositor/Xrenderer/GLX/Hybrid) the shadows go away.  I found the GLX seems to work best for me.